# Adding a popup to a geojson layer in folium

Tags: python, json, leaflet, geojson, folium

I have the following code which uses this [geojson file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/jzs2yoiesf017hn/volcanoes_json.geojson?dl=0) as input.

```
import folium
markers_geojson='volcanoes_json.geojson'  
map=folium.Map(location=[0,0],zoom_start=6,tiles='Mapbox bright')
map.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open(markers_geojson),name='Volcano').add_child(folium.Popup("A plain pop up string")))    
map.save(outfile='test5.html')
```

The above code produces a leaflet map with markers. The problem is it currently displays a static string (i.e. "A plain pop up string") in the popup message. I don't know how to show a value from the geojson properties (e.g.the STATUS property).

Anyone have any idea of how to implement this?

Answer (score 4):

You need to loop through the file.  The file mentioned below is a simple file that has three columns of lat, long and elevation.

If you create a simple text file in this format, this code loops through a file and adds them.  It gets the columns which have lat, long, elevation and in the popup creates a dynamic popup.

```
data = pandas.read_csv("Volcanoes.txt")
lat = list(data["LAT"])
lon = list(data["LON"])
elev = list(data["ELEV"])

# make a color code for elevation
def color_producer(elevation):
    if elevation < 1000:
        return 'green'
    elif 1000 <= elevation < 3000:
        return 'orange'
    else:
        return 'red'

# set the base map
map = folium.Map(location=[47.0, -122.5], zoom_start=12)

# add an additional tile layer
map.add_tile_layer("Stamen Toner")

fgv = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Volcanoes")

# loop through and plot everything
for lt, ln, el in zip(lat, lon, elev):
    fgv.add_child(folium.CircleMarker(location=[lt, ln], radius = 6, popup=str(el)+" m",
    fill_color=color_producer(el), fill=True,  color = 'grey', fill_opacity=0.7))

fgp = folium.FeatureGroup(name="Population")

# add a map of shading by population
fgp.add_child(folium.GeoJson(data=open('world.json', 'r', encoding='utf-8-sig').read(),
style_function=lambda x: {'fillColor':'green' if x['properties']['POP2005'] < 10000000
else 'orange' if 10000000 <= x['properties']['POP2005'] < 20000000 else 'red'}))



# add the layers
map.add_child(fgv)
map.add_child(fgp)
map.add_child(folium.LayerControl())
```

Answer (score 1):

Kindly load your customized html design geojson file and call that after loading like this one

[image]

1. I am working Django please install necessary module | packages
   1.[Geojson](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0vF.png): [geojson Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramaforu/Australia_states/main/aus_states.geojson)
2. [CSV](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bO0vF.png):
   [map Example](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/ramaforu/Australia_states/main/state_map.csv)

   > def new_test_map(request, *args, **kwargs): file_path=
   > os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,tatic/map/geojson/aus_states.geojson')

   ```
    suburbs_json = json.load(open(file_path, "r"))
    file_path=os.path.join(settings.BASE_DIR,"static/map/state_map.csv")
    suburbs_data = pd.read_csv(file_path)
    suburbs_id_map={}
    for feature in suburbs_json["features"]:
        feature["id"] = feature["properties"]["STATE_CODE"]
        suburbs_id_map[feature["properties"]["STATE_NAME"]] = feature["id"]
    suburbs_data["id"] = suburbs_data['state'].apply(lambda x: suburbs_id_map[x])
    suburbs_data.fillna(0)

    def datass(feature):
        k1=suburbs_data.loc[(suburbs_data['id'] == feature)].values.tolist()
        print(k1)
        try:
            k=int(k1[0][5])
            # if k <=1:
            #     risk='No Risk'
            #     color='#808080'
            if k<=1:
                l=k1[0][0]
                return l
            if k == 2:
                risk='Significant Risk'
                color='#edcf64'
            elif k == 3:
                risk='High Risk'
                color= '#be2a3e'    
            html=f"""<div class="card col " style="border-radius:6px;border-top: 6px solid {color};"><div class="card-body">
                            <div style='display:flex;justify-content:space-between'">
                                <h6 class="card-title mb-4" style="font-size: 14px;">State:{k1[0][0]}</h6>
                                <h6 class="card-title mb-1" style="font-size: 14px;color: {color}">{risk}<br></h6>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                            <table class="table align-middle table-nowrap mb-0">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr>
                                        <th scope="col" >MECHANISM</th>
                                        <th scope="col">%</th>
                                        <th scope="col">INCIDENTS</th>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td>{k1[0][6]}</td>
                                        <td>{k1[0][8]}</td>
                                        <td >{k1[0][10]}</td>

                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>

                                        <td >{k1[0][7]}</td>
                                        <td >{k1[0][9]}</td>
                                        <td >{k1[0][11]}</td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                        <p class="mb-0" style="font-size: 11px;">
                                FORECAST ACCURACY +-10%
                        </p>
                        <p class="mb-0" style="font-size: 9px;">
                                updated on {k1[0][12]}
                        </p>
                    </div>
                </div>          
                """
            #print(feature,html)
            return html
        except:
            return k1.Suburb_Name


    for feature in suburbs_json["features"]:
        feature["properties"]["popups"]=datass(feature['id'])
    def style_function_opcity_suburb(feature):
        k1=suburbs_data[(suburbs_data['id'] == feature['id'])]
        try:
            k=int(k1.risk)
        except:
            k=0
        if k >1:
            return 1
        else:
            return 0
    def style_function_suburb(feature):
        k1=suburbs_data[(suburbs_data['id'] == feature['id'])]
        try:
            k=int(k1.risk)
        except:
            k=0
        if k == 1:
            return '#ffffff'
        elif k == 2:
            return '#edcf64'
        elif k == 3:
            return '#be2a3e'    
        else:
            return '#ffffff'

    m = folium.Map(location=[-23.85077947836127, 134.5773586588719],zoom_start=4)
    folium.GeoJson(
        suburbs_json,
        style_function=lambda feature: {
            'fillColor': style_function_suburb(feature),
            'color':'black', 
            'fillOpacity':style_function_opcity_suburb(feature), 
            'weight': 0.1,
        },
        highlight_function=lambda feature: {
            'fillColor': style_function_suburb(feature),
            'color':'black', 
            'fillOpacity': style_function_opcity_suburb(feature), 
            'weight': 2,
        },
        tooltip=folium.features.GeoJsonTooltip(
            fields=['popups'],
            labels=False,
            style=("background-color: white; color: #333333; font-family: arial; 
            font-size: 12px; padding: 10px;") 
        )
    ).add_to(m)
    folium.TileLayer('cartodbpositron').add_to(m)
    m=m._repr_html_() #updated
    return render(request, 'test_map.html', {'my_map':m})
   ```

It works fine. Let me know if anything needs to be optimized...

Answer (score 1):

You can do this without a loop by making use of the `GeoJsonPopup` function.

With your code this would be something like:

```
import folium
markers_geojson='volcanoes_json.geojson'  
m=folium.Map(location=[0,0],zoom_start=6,tiles='Mapbox bright')
geoj = folium.GeoJson(data=open(markers_geojson), name='Volcano')
folium.features.GeoJsonPopup(fields=['VolcanoHeight'], labels=True).add_to(geoj)
geoj.add_to(m)
```